# How to play two background audio tracks simultaneously

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I'm using the '[BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/hh202978%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)' class to play background  audio in windows phone 7.1, now I'm wondering whether I can play two background  audio tracks simultaneously or not.

any thoughts?

ps.If there is no need to play in background, how can I play two audio tracks simultaneously?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The BackgroundAudioPlayer doesn't support this unless you were to use an AudioStreamingSource and combine them yourself.

Doing this in the foreground could be achieved with multiple `MediaElement`'s.

It's very unusual to play multiple sounds at once. Especially if you need them in sync or there's a possibility they may sound bad when played together.
If you're really just need to play sound effects, you should be using the [SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282429%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Cause I want to mix some tracks up to make different sound effects.